# Сумма всех элементов во вложенном списке

Tags: python, numpy

Короче, есть 4-х уровневый список, в котором нужно сложить все элементы.
Вопрос: есть ли готовый функционал для этого в numpy?
Список я генерирую так:

```
def create_random_weights(struct: list,
                          min_val: float = -1,
                          max_val: float = 1) -> list:
    out = []
    for i in range(len(struct)-1):
        out.append([[np.random.rand(2)*(max_val-min_val)+min_val for _ in range(sum(struct[:i+1]))] for _ in range(struct[i+1])])
    return out
```

Comment: `np.sum` не подходит?